# Can't Block a Website using Host File (Only Safari)?

Tags: safari, dns, hosts

I'm trying to block this website: `www.blackhatworld.com` using the host file. The lines I use are this one:

```
127.0.0.1 website.com www.website.com
::1 website.com www.website.com
```

For some reason, this website keeps loading correctly in Safari. In Chrome and Firefox it does not load (as expected). I've tried to flush the DNS Cache & Restart the Mac, but no success so far.

What could be the cause of the problem? I think it has to do with DNS record 65 (HTTPS) as stated in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972371/why-does-etc-hosts-not-work-anymore-for-some-websites-on-big-sur

P.S. all other websites that I have in my host file are being blocked correctly

Comment: DNS is something your computer uses to resolve host names, it's not something a website does. So I'm not sure what "This website is using Cloudflare DNS for resolving" means.

Comment: I've changed my DNS Resolver IPs to Google's but the problem keeps happening, so it's not an issue of Cloudflare apparently.

Comment: Do you have "Hide IP Address" enabled in Safari Privacy Settings

Comment: Yes, I have that option enabled, however, that is not related at all with the problem.